# Which preposition should be used after the verb “request”?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which is correct?

1. *I would like to request you to refrain from shouting.*
2. *I would like to request of you to refrain from shouting.*
3. *I would like to request from you to refrain from shouting.*
4. Something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

3 is out: one might request an item from a person, but not generally a behavior.

2 is correct but the "of" is unnecessary.

1 just sounds better than the others because it is less wordy.

However, the most direct is, "Please refrain from shouting." Why make it complicated?

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the question at the end of your answer: Because that’s not the point in my question. My question is how to use the verb “request”. “Don’t use it” might be a solution *in this particular example sentence*, but it doesn’t answer the general question.

Comment: Really?? I find (1) to be ungrammatical.

Comment: I do not find any of these to be ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

There is another obvious one to add to your list:

> “I would like to request you refrain from shouting.”

I think there are people who use all three forms you suggested. It's a little difficult to say which one is correct but as kajaco said 3. sounds a bit odd.

Comment: Or, indeed, "I would like to request _that_ you refrain from shouting" which sounds the most grammatical to my (Australian English-acclimatised) ears.

Comment: @Cowan: Exactly. "That" can often be omitted, but it can often sound a bit dodgy/sloppy. Best to include "that", you can never go wrong with it.

Comment: @Noldorin: so that is the reason you downvoted my post? You're a hero.

Comment: I'm sorry. Did I hurt your feelings?

Comment: @Noldorin: please use your question and answer votes to promote or demote the answers which you feel are correct or incorrect, without worrying about whether you are hurting my feelings.

Comment: You clearly missed my sarcasm.

Comment: @Noldorin: you missed mine too.

Comment: Yes, in my dialect I wouldn't use the infinitive "to refrain" with "request of" or "request from".

Comment: to request YOU is not grammatical in English. As Cowan said: request THAT you etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

I would like to request *that* you to refrain from shouting.

Comment: That seems ungrammatical to me.

Comment: +1 This is exactly correct. One requests *that* someone does something. (*that* can sometimes be omitted, but may be considered sloppy). Compare the Google results for "request that you" (50M) and "request you" (3M).

Comment: I agree with Shinto: "to refrain" should be simply "refrain" in the sentence above.

Comment: _I would like to request that you refrain from shouting_ is correct, but not _I would like to request that you to refrain from shouting._ The sentence is made of two clauses: _I would like to request_, and _you refrain from shouting._ You don't say (**?**) _you to refrain from shouting._

Comment: Oops, I read this too quickly. I suspect it was written too quickly too! Up-vote removed.

Comment: I think someone should just edit this. The "to" makes all the difference here, but the point is that request should be followed by "that", which I agree with.

Comment: This is the only suggestion that is actually ungrammatical, as combining the subjunctive (after *request*) with an infinitive.  Deleting the 'to' would give a better sentence, but would not be an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

What about "for"?  An RFP is a "request for proposal."

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that it varies. You can:

Request [a person] to [do something]~ 'request visitors to remove their shoes'

Request to have [a thing or a favour]~ request to have his telephone upgraded'

Request for [a thing or favour] ~ 'a request for a new computer'

Request that [something happens] ~ 'request that you refrain from shouting'

Comment: If this is the simple answer, what is the real one? +1 anyway

Comment: request visitor removes their shoes - no to; request a new computer, no for.